# PHP references doesn't work in Laravel macros

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, macros

Trying to make a helper method for array that replaces key into given value without return using reference but it doesn't work.

```
Arr::macro('replaceKey', function (string $from, string $into, array &$inside) {
    if (! array_key_exists($from, $inside)) {
        throw new Exception("Undefined offset: $from");
    }

    $inside[$into] = $inside[$from];

    unset($inside[$from]);
});
```

Tried the same thing with trait and simple function and it works.

```
// inside trait

public function replaceKey(string $from, string $into, array &$inside)
{
    if (! array_key_exists($from, $inside)) {
        throw new Exception("Undefined offset: $from");
    }

    $inside[$into] = $inside[$from];

    unset($inside[$from]);
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method call before your anonymous function would be getting called when you call a macro; `__callStatic` gets called. This takes a method name and an array of parameters passed to the method call.

It isn't possible from the method signature side of this method, `__callStatic`, to declare that an element of the parameters array is to be a reference since it only receives an array of all the arguments passed to the non existing method, `replaceKey`, as an argument.

You are getting a reference to a copy of the array you are passing to your macro method call in your anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because you are not returning anything from function.

```
public function replaceKey(string $from, string $into, array &$inside)
{
    if (! array_key_exists($from, $inside)) {
        throw new Exception("Undefined offset: $from");
    }

    $inside[$into] = $inside[$from];

    unset($inside[$from]);
    return $inside;
}
```

And macro as well

```
Arr::macro('replaceKey', function (string $from, string $into, array &$inside) {
    if (! array_key_exists($from, $inside)) {
        throw new Exception("Undefined offset: $from");
    }

    $inside[$into] = $inside[$from];

    unset($inside[$from]);
  
  return $inside;
});
```

Comment: I wrote that inside simple trait or helper function it works so first example is needless and in the second one I'm trying to use reference. I know that with return it will work.